# How can I have textview as scrollable inside a stackview and keep it visible?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, textview, stackview

I currently have an app which displays questions and answers as text in textview objects. These textviews are wrapped in stackviews along with navigation buttons.

If I set the textview to non-scrollable (by unchecking the scrollable button) the text displays, but long text runs off the screen and of course the user can't scroll down to read it. If I check the scrollable button, the text isn't displayed at all - just blank space.

Any idea how I can either: set the text to be scrollable and display or set the text to autoshrink (as it doesnt run over by much).

Answer (score 0):

That much to say about textViews -> Replace the textViews with labels with 0 of lines -> This guarantees that the label will be autoshrinking vertically, just set width and the stackView into scrollView and you are at it :)